# How does Model Class work, Django?

Tags: python, django, inheritance

Before posting this question, I have read through the Official Django Documentation, scouring it for a comprehensive explanation for beginners. I have read the code of the actual Model Class, and searched around on StackOverflow.

When working with databases in Django, you work with classes inheriting from the Model class in the models module. This helps programmers avoid double-typing everything, jumping between database specific syntax and python. As I have read, 'the model class that each model inherits from automatically takes care of translation'.

How does this work? How Does the Model Class convert model attributes to database columns? I suppose some methods inherited from the parent Model Class are able to use the variables specified in each new model, but would like a better explanation if possible!

Also, why write 'models.Model' if the Model class is within models.base?

LINK TO MODEL CLASS: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/db/models/base/#Model

EDIT:

Figured out the reason behind why models.Model work.

Comment: What do you mean by "How does this work"? Django's ORM has many, many parts.

Comment: How does the Model Class convert model attributes to database columns? It has become clear to me that inheriting from models.Model bridges python-syntax and database-format. I am just not sure how the Model class works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How Does the Model Class convert model attributes to database columns?

The `Model` class doesn't really do any conversion itself. You create a subclass of `Model` that has some column information, 
which Django's ORM uses when building the database query corresponding to your Django ORM query. The conversion is done by a database driver when it actually communicates with your specific database.

Here's a toy ORM that behaves a little like Django's `Model`. You can implement `QuerySet` for fun if you want:

```
class Column:
    '''
    Represents a database column.

    This is used to create the underlying table in the database
    and to translate database types to Python types.
    '''

    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type


class Manager:
    '''
    Accessed via `YourModel.objects`. This is what constructs
    a `QuerySet` object in Django.
    '''

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model

    def get(self, id):
        '''
        Pretend `YourModel.objects.get(id=123)` queries the database directly.
        '''

        # Create an instance of the model. We only keep track of the model class.
        instance = self.model()

        # Populate the instance's attributes with the result of the database query
        for name in self.model._columns:
            # Pretend we load the values from the database
            value = 123
            setattr(instance, name, value)

        # This would be done above if we actually queried the database
        instance.id = id

        # Finally return the instance of `self.model`
        return instance


class ModelBase(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        new_cls = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

        # The `Manager` instance is made a class attribute
        new_cls.objects = Manager(new_cls)

        # Keep track of the columns for conveniece
        new_cls._columns = {}

        for name, attr in attrs.items():
            if isinstance(attr, Column):
                new_cls._columns[name] = attr

        # The class is now ready
        return new_cls


class Model(metaclass=ModelBase):
    '''
    Django's `Model` is more complex.
    This one only uses `ModelBase` as its metaclass so you can just inherit from it
    '''
    pass


class MyModel(Model):
    id = Column(int)
    column2 = Column(float)
    column3 = Column(str)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(MyModel._columns)

    instance = MyModel.objects.get(id=5)
    print(instance.id)
```

The main functionality is provided by `Model` having `ModelBase` as a metaclass. The metaclass's `__new__` method is called 
when `Model` or any subclass is created (not an instance, the class itself), which allows the metaclass to modify the class arbitrarily.
Each `Model` subclass contains information about its own columns and gets a `objects` class attribute that queries the database for it.

> Also, why write 'models.Model' if the Model class is within models.base?

`models/__init__.py` imports `Model` from `models/base.py` so you don't have to write `models.base.Model`.

Comment: what is this type in `class ModelBase(type):` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a model class and run

`python manage.py makemigrations`

It creates the corresponding scripts to create a table in your database.
You can find this script in your apps "migrations" folder.

And when you run

`python manage.py migrate`

These scripts are mapped to the correct commands and are executed on the database by Django.

Comment: I was wondering more specifically regarding the model class, and the functionality of that class. And do you know why I have to write models.model when the Model class seems to be within models.base?

Comment: Django models is an integral part of Django's ORM. As far as i can understand, your question is how does Django converts the models you write into corresponsding SQL commands and converts it into columns of tables in DB. The concept is called ORM (Object Relational Mapping). Please read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping. If you're coming from a language,where you have to write the SQL commands directly, this might look like magic,but Django abstracts it into the Django models library. To explain the complete functionality of Django models is beyond scope